# Array of threads and attempting to pass multiple arguments to function is not working?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I am creating a program with a dynamic number of threads. I have a vector for the threads (thanks, Mohamad); then I attempt to call a function and pass multiple arguments for the thread of execution.

However, my current code gives an error which I assume is due to my odd usage of the 2D array:

> In function 'int main()': 102 77  [Error] no matching function for call
>   to 'std::thread::thread(void (&)(float (*)[2], float*, int, int),
>   float [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)nodeNumber) + -1)) + 1)][2], float
>   [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)nodeNumber) + -1)) + 1)], int&, int&)'
>
> 102   77      [Note] candidates are: 4    0
>
> 133   7   c:\program files
>   (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\thread [Note]
>   template
>   std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)
>
> 133   7   c:\program files
>   (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\thread [Note]
>   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>
> 102   77      [Note] variable-sized array type 'float
>   (&)[(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)nodeNumber) + -1)) + 1)][2]' is not a
>   valid template argument
>
> 4 0   In file included from
>
> 128   5   c:\program files
>   (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\thread [Note]
>   std::thread::thread(std::thread&&)
>
> 128   5   c:\program files
>   (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\thread [Note]
>   candidate expects 1 argument, 5 provided
>
> 122   5   c:\program files
>   (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\thread [Note]
>   std::thread::thread() 122 5   c:\program files
>   (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\thread [Note]
>   candidate expects 0 arguments, 5 provided

Here are some of the chunks of code where I am attempting this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


void map(float rank_matrix[][2], float adjacency_matrix[], int nodeNumber, int node);

int main()  {
    // setup code, initialization section here

        float adjacency_matrix[nodeNumber][nodeNumber];
        float rank_matrix[nodeNumber][2];

    while(iter < terminate)  {

        vector<thread> threads;

        for(int i = 0; i < nodeNumber; i++)  {
            threads.push_back(std::thread(map, rank_matrix, adjacency_matrix[i], nodeNumber, i);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < nodeNumber; i++)  {
            threads.join();
        }

        // Flush out the mass for each node (will be updated based on mapper's work.
        for(i = 0; i < nodeNumber; i++)  {
            rank_matrix[i][0] = 0;
        }

        iter++;
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


// Mapper code for each individual node and computation.
void map(float rank_matrix[][2], float adjacency_matrix[], int nodeNumber,    int node)  {
    for(int i = 0; i < nodeNumber; i++)  {
        if(rank_matrix[node][1] != 0 && adjacency_matrix[i] > 0)
            adjacency_matrix[i] = (rank_matrix[node][0] / rank_matrix[node][1]); 
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?  Help would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: I edited the error message for you.  You can always select everything you want to block quote and then press the " button

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to remember that next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
thread myThread[nodeNumber];
```

This creates a number of default-initialized threads i.e threads that do not represent any thread of execution.

```
myThread[i](map, rank_matrix, adjacency_matrix[i], nodeNumber, i);
```

Does not initialize your threads.

I would suggest using a vector of threads like in this [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/thread/)

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
```

This does not create any actual threads. Just the container to hold them.

Then you can populate it like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < nodeNumber; i++)  {
    threads.push_back(std::thread(map, rank_matrix, adjacency_matrix[i], nodeNumber, i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried your suggestion, but I get this error: [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(void (&)(float (*)[2], float*, int, int), float [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)nodeNumber) + -1)) + 1)][2], float [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)nodeNumber) + -1)) + 1)], int&, int&)'

Comment: I included the vector library.  I'm wondering if it doesn't like my map function.  Basically, the adjacency_matrix is a 2D array, but I have hacked it so that I only pass in rows and do calculations.  It works without using threads when I test it.  Now I am just trying to use threads to split work between pieces of the array (using the nodes).

Comment: Could you edit your existing post or ask another question and post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post just enough code to allow us to fire it up and see what the problem is.

Comment: I think the issue is the variable sized array adjacency_matrix.

Comment: Does your example compile for you? Because it doesn't for me.

Comment: It doesn't compile because of the errors I posted.  I know the map function works because I can use it without threading.

Comment: I'm going to delete this question and tweak a few things and come back later.  Since I know the problem isn't the way I'm doing the threads, I think my function arguments must have some problem.  I'll be back with a new post if I can't figure it out.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I gave you credit, though, because your answer in general will help other users.

Answer (score 2):

```
myThread[i](map, rank_matrix, adjacency_matrix[i], nodeNumber, i);
```

Is attemting to call the function call operator on `myThread[i]` with the supplied parameters not calling a constructor.  `thread myThread[nodeNumber];` already constructs the threads so what you need to do is assign a thread to each element of the array

```
myThread[i] = thread(map, rank_matrix, adjacency_matrix[i], nodeNumber, i);
```